# How to consistently track location with Fused Location Provider on background?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play, google-play-services

I am developing app tracking location every 20 minutes. I implemented FusedLocationProvider with ForegroundService according to Android documentation. My main goal is to track location for long time. Typical use case could be a day with locked screen whole time.

**Expected Results**
To track location every 20 minutes on background. It doesn't have to be exactly 20 minutes - as it is in the documentation it could be slightly more.

**Actual Results**
Right now my implementation sends location every 20 minutes when screen is locked for couple hours without any issue. After couple hours the interval is changed and location is retrieved every two or three hours for instance.

From my experience if I just unlock the device and immediately lock it back everything works as expected as it is in actual results. It seems when screen is locked for long time app has less resources. My question is if this is expected behaviour of FusedLocationProvider?

As I mentioned I followed Android documentation and here is my code:

**Android Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service android:name="com.xamarin.LocUpdFgService.LocationUpdatesService" 
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:exported="true" 
        android:foregroundServiceType="location">
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:host="com.xamarin.LocUpdFgService.LocationUpdatesService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

**LocationRequest implementation**

```
LocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
LocationRequest.SetInterval(UpdateIntervalInMilliseconds);
LocationRequest.SetPriority(LocationRequest.PriorityHighAccuracy);
```

Comment: With the changes that came with dose in Android 6, the applications are given fewer resources so they do not consume too much battery. If you read this android post https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby you will realise that this is the expected behaviour!

Comment: Agree with FreakyAli, but you can leader users to open list of apps for choosing battery optimization   `Intent i = new Intent();
       i.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionIgnoreBatteryOptimizationSettings);
            StartActivity(i);`